# Autolayout and UIImageViews

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiimageview, autolayout

I have a series of views. Into each, I want to place a different image. These images have different aspect ratios, but the largest dimension is exactly 40pts, whether it be the height or the width. The image should be scaled to fill a space in the center of its view such that its widest dimension is 30pts, while maintaining its aspect ratio.

I have set the `contentScaleFactor` on the `UIImageView` to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`.

I then added two constraints - one to constrain the width to <= 30 and another to constrain the height to <= 30.

But the image is always stretched to exactly 30 x 30.

How can I specify the maximum size for the image but maintain its aspect ratio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `contentMode` to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` on the UIImageView and not the `contentScaleFactor`.

`contentScaleFactor` is the mapping of the points to pixels on screen.